# Como puedo hacer un join de atributos en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
module Countries
  class GetFlightCoordinator
    attr_reader :arrival_airport, :departure_airport_id, :arrival_airport_id, :departure_date, :country_id, :flights

    def initialize(country_id:, departure_airport_id:, arrival_airport_id:, flights:)
      @departure_airport_id = departure_airport_id
      @arrival_airport_id = arrival_airport_id
      @departure_airport = Airport.find_by(id: @departure_airport_id)
      @arrival_airport = Airport.find_by(id: @arrival_airport_id)
      @country_id = country_id
      @flights = flights
    end

    def call
      country_flights = Country.joins(flights.arrival_airport_id, flights.departure_airport_id).where(Airport.country_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Este es el codigo de mi coordinator. Mi objetivo es que dado un pais realizar una lista con todos los vuelos que entren y salgan (departure y arrival) del mismo. Lo cierto es que estoy dando mis primeros pasos en ruby y estoy un poco perdido.

Estos son los modelos COuntry y Flight

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :airports, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :departure_airport, class_name: 'Airport'
  belongs_to :arrival_airport, class_name: 'Airport'

  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :arrival_date, :departure_date, presence: true
  validates_with ArrivalDateValidator
  validates_with ArrivalAirportValidator
end
```

Comment: Si tienes relaciones en los modelos, solo basta con llamar `join(:relacion)`; ¿podemos ver tus modelos `Country` y `Flight`?

Comment: @Gerry alli los agregue a la pregunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi objetivo es que dado un pais

Si es dado un país, solo necesitarías el `@country_id`

> realizar una lista con todos los vuelos que entren y salgan (departure y arrival) del mismo

Si necesitas vuelos, entonces la consulta debes realizarla sobre `Flight` y no `Country`. Creo que la consulta quedaría algo como esto:

```
Flight.joins(<<-SQL).where(airports: { country_id: @country_id })
  INNER JOIN airports ON airports.id = flights.departure_airport_id OR 
                         airports.id = flights.arrival_airport_id
SQL
```